# Prove that the language Cats-Vs-Dogs is undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, undecidability

Define Σ = {a, b, c, . . . , z} be the set of letters in the English alphabet.
Prove that the following language is undecidable:
Cats-VS-Dogs = {(M) | Either “cats” ∈ L(M) or “dogs” ∈ L(M), but not both.}.

Answer (score 1):

[Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) will give a direct and simple proof for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet learned Rice's Theorem you can use a Turing reduction here, which is essentially a proof by contradiction. We want to show that some undecidable problem can be reduced to Cats-Vs-Dogs, which would mean that if we could decide Cats-VS-Dogs, we could decide that undecidable problem, a contradiction! Let's use the halting problem. We know that the language {<M,w> | M halts on w} is undecidable.

Suppose Cats-VS-Dogs is decidable and let T be a decider for it. Construct the TM S as follows:

On input: <S',w> 
$\quad$ Construct Machine M as follows: 
$\quad\quad$ On input x: 
$\quad\quad\quad$ if x is 'dogs' ACCEPT 
$\quad\quad\quad$ run S' on w 
$\quad\quad\quad$ if x is 'cats' ACCEPT 
$\quad$ Run T on <M> 
$\quad$ If T accepts REJECT otherwise ACCEPT

Notice that if S' halts on w then L(M) contains both 'dogs' and 'cats,' so when we run T on <M> T will reject since it decides the Cats-VS-Dogs problem, in this case S accepts. On the other hand if S' does not halt on w then L(S') contains 'dogs' but not 'cats' since running S' on w will never halt. In this case when running T on <M> T will accept, so S rejects. Then L(S) = {<M,w> | M halts on w}.

Also notice that the machine called M is never run by S, just constructed and its description passed to T. Since T decides Cats-VS-Dogs T always halts, so S always halts too. Then S decides {<M,w> | M halts on w} and we have obtained our contradiction!